# Adding hyperlink to PHP -ZendFramework

Tags: php, zend-framework, hyperlink

I would like to add hyperlinks dynamically to the cell of a specific column in my datatable. I'm working with Zend Framework. I've tried this :

```
    <?php 
        foreach ($this ->paginator as $key =>$value)
        {
            $path = $value->path;
            echo $path ;
            echo '<tr><td>'.$value->id.'</td><td>'.$value->name.'</td><td>'.
            $value->size.'</td><td>'.$value->created.'</td><td><a href= "$path">'.$path
            .'</a></td><td>'.$value->clientname.'</td><td>'.$value->type.'</td><td>'.$value->hashname.'</td><td>'.$value->ext.'</td></tr>';
        }
    ?>
```

but when I click on path , URL appears like this:

```
http://website.com/admin/test/test2/test3/$path
```

I guess it's relevant to `<a href ="$path">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `'</td><td><a href= "$path">'` to `'</td><td><a href="'.$path.'">'`

Answer (score 0):

Just instead

```
<a href ="$path">
```

By:

```
<a href=".$path.">
```